# With a Python interpreter embedded in C++ how do I override the 'print()' function so that it prints to my own separate console?

Tags: python, c++, interpreter

So I am embedding a Python interpreter within C++. I am just using the regular Python installation for my interpreter and Numpy. I don't have the advantage of the default console to print to so I will have to construct my own. So I would like to find out if there is some way to reprogram the print() function to do what I want. I know that there is operator overloading within C++ but how could I achieve this within the interpreter, because the print() function does take any type.

Comment: Are you trying to redefine what `print` does, or just where print sends its result?  Within Python `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr` are just variables, and you can change them to be a different stream.

Comment: Reconfiguring print may be fairly difficult, and any way of doing so will probably mean you need to import the new definition anywhere you need to use it. It may be easier to look into python's logging module, which has pretty good flexibility and may be able to fit your use case (plus you'll probably find better documentation for this than for reconfiguring print).